# Reference error in async functions I use in PassportJS

Tags: node.js, promise, passport.js, referenceerror

I have an asynchronous function called getUserByToken and I call it as follows.

```
import { Strategy as BearerStrategy } from "passport-http-bearer";

export const getUserByToken = async (accessToken: string) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await auth.post("/api/me", { accessToken });
    return user;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log({ error });
  }
};

passport.use(
  "auth.jwt",
  new BearerStrategy(async function (accessToken, done) {
    try {
      const user =  await getUserByToken(accessToken);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  })
);
```

the error i got;

```
node:134804) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: getUserByToken is not defined
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/sumeyyemrah/Desktop/momentup/jetlexa/api-clm.jetlexa.com/src/utils/passport/index.ts:57:21), <anonymous>:2:3)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/sumeyyemrah/Desktop/momentup/jetlexa/api-clm.jetlexa.com/src/utils/passport/index.ts:57:21), <anonymous>:3:3)
at Strategy._verify (/home/sumeyyemrah/Desktop/momentup/jetlexa/api-clm.jetlexa.com/src/utils/passport/index.ts:57:21)
at Strategy.authenticate (/home/sumeyyemrah/Desktop/momentup/jetlexa/api-clm.jetlexa.com/node_modules/passport-http-bearer/lib/strategy.js:130:10)
at attempt (/home/sumeyyemrah/Desktop/momentup/jetlexa/api-clm.jetlexa.com/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:366:16)
at authenticate (/home/sumeyyemrah/Desktop/momentup/jetlexa/api-clm.jetlexa.com/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:367:7)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/sumeyyemrah/Desktop/momentup/jetlexa/api-clm.jetlexa.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/home/sumeyyemrah/Desktop/momentup/jetlexa/api-clm.jetlexa.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/home/sumeyyemrah/Desktop/momentup/jetlexa/api-clm.jetlexa.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/sumeyyemrah/Desktop/momentup/jetlexa/api-clm.jetlexa.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /home/sumeyyemrah/Desktop/momentup/jetlexa/api-clm.jetlexa.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (/home/sumeyyemrah/Desktop/momentup/jetlexa/api-clm.jetlexa.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/home/sumeyyemrah/Desktop/momentup/jetlexa/api-clm.jetlexa.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at Function.handle (/home/sumeyyemrah/Desktop/momentup/jetlexa/api-clm.jetlexa.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
at router (/home/sumeyyemrah/Desktop/momentup/jetlexa/api-clm.jetlexa.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/sumeyyemrah/Desktop/momentup/jetlexa/api-clm.jetlexa.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:134804) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:134804) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:134804) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: done is not a function
    at Strategy._verify (/home/sumeyyemrah/Desktop/momentup/jetlexa/api-clm.jetlexa.com/src/utils/passport/index.ts:72:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(node:134804) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
```

Comment: Is the JS shown in a single file, or is this two files and an import issue?

Comment: @DaveNewton they are defined in a single file.

Comment: Potentially related; what's `user` in the `getUserByToken` function? Are you sure everything is compiling correctly?

Comment: sorry, just typo. User is actually data in source code. I shortened the code for stackowerflow. It actually pulls data from 3 different collections over the DB and returns it as a user. @DaveNewton